# Optimize the traversal of a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I want to check for fuzzy duplicates in a column of the dataframe using fuzzywuzzy.
In this case, I have to iterate over the rows one by one using two nested for loops.

```
for i in df['col']:
    for j in df['col']:
       ratio = fuzz.ratio(i, j)
       if ratio > 90:
           print("row duplicates")
```

Except that my dataframe contains `600 000 rows`, and this code has a complexity of `0(n²)`.
Is there a lighter way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case I would recommend the usage of [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) (I am the author). In particular the function `process.cdist` should allow you to implement this very efficiently:

```py
import numpy as np
from rapidfuzz import fuzz, process

process.cdist(df['col'], df['col'],
    scorer=fuzz.ratio, dtype=np.uint8, score_cutoff=90, workers=-1)
```

Note that this creates a matrix of size `len(df['col']) * len(df['col'])`, which would be way to large when working with 600.000 elements (around 335 GB). To reduce the memory usage you can compare the strings in multiple smaller steps:

```py
process.cdist(df['col'][0:10000], df['col'][0:10000],
    scorer=fuzz.ratio, dtype=np.uint8, score_cutoff=90, workers=-1)
```

Note that since your comparing the row to itself you can skip some sections of this matrix, since `fuzz.ratio(df['col'][1], df['col'][0]) == fuzz.ratio(df['col'][0], df['col'][1])`.